# How to disable swagger when Junit runs? - without using conditional beans with @profile

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

We would like to skip the Swagger for unit tests altogether.

One way of doing this is with conditional beans as in :

```
@Profile("dev,qa,prod")
@Configuration
```

ref: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/328

But we would like to take that decision not based on profiles but rather on the mere fact that whether we are in a test context or not. How could we achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish that using **@Profile({ "!test && swagger" })** as:

```
@Configuration
@Profile({ "!test && swagger" })
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
```

Hope it helps.